# Get QTableView cell text after delegate

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, qtableview

I change the text of a column of QTableView by using `displaytext` function in `QStyledItemDelegate` class.

```
QString Msg_NameGIdDelegate::displayText(const QVariant &value, const QLocale &locale) const
{
    return Diag_Utility::getMsgNameStr(value.toInt());
}
```

How I can get the text of each cell in this column after delegate. If I use the following code I get the text before delegation.

```
for(int i=0; i<ui->msgCount_tableView->model()->rowCount();i++)
    qDebug()<<ui->msgCount_tableView->model()->index(i,6).data().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you change delegate text but not change model data and you are fetching model data and you want delegate data.

[`QAbstractItemDelegate *QAbstractItemView::itemDelegate(const QModelIndex &index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#itemDelegate-1) function will return your delegate so you can get `displayText`.

If this solution doesn't work you change model's data by `model()->setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role = Qt::EditRole)`function instead of delegate's `displayText` and you can fetch `model->data()`